# Rails: How to replace :if and :unless option for rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in application_controller.rb:4

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :prepare_meta_tags, if: "request.get?"
```

Rails 5.1 WARNING

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing string to be evaluated in :if and :unless conditional options is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.2 without replacement. Pass a symbol for an instance method, or a lambda, proc or block, instead. (called from <class:ApplicationController> at MYSITE/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:4)
```

Question:

1. What is option in :if and :unless in that clause to be rewrite
2. And how to rewrite for compliance with rails 5.2

I have if and unless all over in my project. Need advice. Thanks

Answer (score 41, accepted):

First of all, don't worry they are not deprecating :if and :unless. They are deprecating passing a string to it.

Using lambda instead is way better in this case

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :prepare_meta_tags, if: -> { request.get? }
...
end
```