# How do I adjust conditional to pass a symbol for an instance method in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm upgrading from a rails 5.0 to 5.2, and I'm getting the error:

`Passing string to be evaluated in :if and :unless conditional options is not supported. Pass a symbol for an instance method, or a lambda, proc or block, instead.`

I found this question [How to replace :if and :unless option for rails 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46719763/how-to-replace-if-and-unless-option-for-rails-5-2)

But I wasn't sure how to apply it to my conditional.

In my devise.rb initializer file, I have this:

```
  Rails.application.config.to_prepare do
    Devise::RegistrationsController.layout proc { |controller| user_signed_in? ? "application" : "registration" }
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to change `“application”` and `“registration”` to `:application` and `:registration`.